# Is there a better way to calculate "Padovan sequence" than O(n)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

Current code in `Java`:

```
public static BigInteger gen(long n) {
    if (n <= 2) return ONE;

    BigInteger a = ONE, b = ONE, c = ONE;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        BigInteger x = a.add(b);
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = x;
    }

    return c;
}
```

Above function is O(n), but is there a O(1) solution ?

Comment: Vast amount of information about Padovans at http://oeis.org/A000931 including programs in many different computer languages and links to dozens of papers. Maybe the most promising formula for rapid computation is $a(n) = (r^n)/(2r+3) + (s^n)/(2s+3) + (t^n)/(2t+3)$ where $r, s, t$ are the three roots of $x^3-x-1$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson
This is computationally very inefficient since $r,s,t$ are irrationals and for big $n$ a very high precision would be necessary in order to calculate the Padovan number. This formulas for linear recurrence sequences are called "formulas of Binet type" (after the Binet formula for Fibonacci numbers) and are almost never used to actually calculate the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, consider the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\ 
0&0&1\\ 
1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $A^{n+1}= \begin{pmatrix}
P_{n-4}&P_{n-2}&P_{n-3}\\ 
P_{n-3}&P_{n-1}&P_{n-2}\\ 
P_{n-2}&P_n&P_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$ and you can use binary exponentiation [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to calculate the matrix power.

Comment: This works, just rewrote the program with this algorithm, generating 1,000,000 th number took less than 1 second on my laptop, much better.

Comment: By the way, this gives a $O(\log n)$ solution. No $O(1)$ solution is possible.

Comment: Yeah, O(log(n)) is good enough for any n within range of `long` I guess, the bigger issue is the result String may grow so large that there will be not enough memory to store it ...

Comment: BTW, just found `fibonacci` can be impl in similar way. just change the initial matrix, the formula is at: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciQ-Matrix.html, gonna learn more about matrix related math, seems powerful.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence#Binet-like_formula) gives $P(n)$ is the integer closest to $s^{-1}p^{n-1}$ where $p$ is the real root of $x^3-x-1=0$ and $s$ is the real root of $s^3-2s^2+23s-23=0$. There are efficient methods for calculating $p$ and $s$ to as many decimal places as needed, and the standard exponentiation technique computes $p^{n-1}$ in a number of steps logarithmic in $n$.

EDIT: Here's another method, which may be equivalent to the matrix method in the other answer, but without the matrices.

If you have $a(n),a(n+1),a(n+2),a(n+3)$ then you can calculate $a(2n),a(2n+1),a(2n+2),a(2n+3)$ using ten multiplications (three of which are multiplications by two) and a few additions using

$a(2n)=a(n)^2+2a(n+1)a(n+2)$
$a(2n+1)=2a(n)a(n+1)+a(n+1)^2+a(n+2)^2$
$a(2n+2)=a(n+1)^2+2a(n+2)a(n+3)$
$a(2n+3)=a(2n)+a(2n+1)$.

The formulas may have to be adjusted a bit depending on how you are indexing the sequence (that is, what you are taking as $a(1),a(2),a(3)$).

So, suppose you want $a(1,000,000)$.
You can get this from $a(499,999),a(500,000),a(500,001),a(500,002)$.
You can get these from $a(249,999),a(250,000),a(250,001),a(250,002)$.
You can get these from $a(124,999),a(125,000),a(125,001),a(125,002)$.
You can get these from $a(62,499),a(62,500),a(62,501),a(62,502)$.
You can get these from $a(31,249),a(31,250),a(31,251),a(31,252)$.
You can get these from $a(15,624),a(15,625),(a(15,626),a(15,627)$.
You can get these from $a(7,812),a(7,813),a(7,814),a(7,815)$.
You can get these from $a(3,906),a(3,907),a(3,908),a(3,909)$.
You can get these from $a(1,953),a(1,954),a(1,955),a(1,956)$.
You can get these from $a(977),a(978),a(979),a(980)$.
You can get these from $a(489),a(490),a(491),a(492)$.
You can get these from $a(245),a(246),a(247),a(248)$.
You can get these from $a(123),a(124),a(125),a(126)$.
You can get these from $a(62),a(63),a(64),a(65)$.
It may make sense to have $a(1),a(2),\dots,a(100)$ stored in memory.

Comment: This is computationally very inefficient since the root is irrational and for big n a very high precision would be necessary in order to calculate the Padovan number. This formulas for linear recurrence sequences are called "formulas of Binet type" (after the Binet formula for Fibonacci numbers) and are almost never used to actually calculate the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, but I am pretty sure now thant the `pow of matrix` is the best solution, it's easy to impl, and very quick O(log(n)), as the accepted answer states. I already implemented it, and it passed tests. That solution can also apply to sequence like fibonacci, most of the code can be reused.

Comment: For Fibonacci, from $f(n),f(n+1),f(n+2)$ you can get $f(2n),f(2n+1),f(2n+2)$ by $f(2n)=(f(n))^2+(f(n+1))^2$, $f(2n+2)=(f(n+1))^2+(f(n+2))^2$, $f(2n+1)=f(2n+2)-f(2n)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The formula using matrix for fibonacci is here:https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciQ-Matrix.html, I already impl it & tested, it also works.